# Can we configure kube-router network policy from Azure Kubernetes Service using ARM Template

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-rm-template, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy to an AKS cluster using ARM templates. I downloaded the generated template from the Azure portal, but couldn't figure out "kube-router" network policies through ARM template.

Is there a way to do this through ARM template?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, "kube-router" is a service of Kubernetes. You can get something useful from [here](https://carlos.mendible.com/2018/07/19/at-last-network-policies-in-aks-with-kube-router/).

You can find all the configuration of template for Azure Kubernetes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters). So it seems you cannot set the "kube-router" network policies through ARM template. But you can take a look at the "networkProfile" of the AKS properties and there is a network Policy.